# Zip() combines lists into one tuple

Tags: python-3.x

```
names = input("Enter list of names separated by commas\n").split()
assignments = input("Enter list of number of assignments separated by commas\n").split()
grades = input("Enter list of grades separated by commas\n").split()
students = list(zip(names,assignments,grades))
print(students)
```

Input:

```
Enter list of names separated by commas
Lina,Dina,Sarah
Enter list of number of assignments separated by commas
2,1,2
Enter list of grades separated by commas
2.8,2.9,3.0
```

Output:

```
[('Lina,Dina,Sarah', '2,1,2', '2.8,2.9,3.0')]
```

I don't know why it doesn't get expected output like:

```
[('Lina',2,2.8),('Dina',1,2.9),('Sarah',2,3.0)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split by comma according to your input

```
names = input("Enter list of names separated by commas\n").split(",")
assignments = list(map(int,input("Enter list of number of assignments separated by commas\n").split(",")))
grades = list(map(float,input("Enter list of grades separated by commas\n").split(",")))
students = list(zip(names,assignments,grades))
print(students)
```

Output:

```
Enter list of names separated by commas
Lina,Dina,Sarah
Enter list of number of assignments separated by commas
2,1,2
Enter list of grades separated by commas
2.8,2.9,3.0
[('Lina', 2, 2.8), ('Dina', 1, 2.9), ('Sarah', 2, 3.0)]
```